# DocuSign: when using an embedded signer, how do you send email to user if they select "Finish Later"

Tags: docusignapi

DocuSign: when using an embedded signer, how do you send email to the signer if they select "Finish Later?"

I have tried to deselect the "Suppress Emails to Embedded Signers". But that did not seem to change anything.

If it is not possible to send a signer an email, how does they get back to the document, since the url that is generated is only good for 5 minutes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DocuSign offers two main methods for initiating workflows with your recipients:  **Remote** Recipients or **Embedded** Recipients.

**Remote Recipients**, which is the default, receive an email from the DocuSign platform which has a link that they use to open the signature request through a browser and sign through the DocuSign Web App (i.e. website).  In this scenario recipients are guided through the DocuSign website and have full access to all features and settings.

On the other hand, **Embedded Recipients** do not context-switch, wait for an email, and then sign through the website.  Instead, when you embed a given recipient you are telling the DocuSign platform that YOU are taking care of everything, such as preparing the signing URL, delivering to the user (recipient), and handling the callback once they are done signing.

In this case, whether they sign the document, decline to sign, close the window, or do something else like hit the "Finish Later" button, there will be a query parameter appended to the return URL you configure so that you can determine what action they took.  For instance if they declined to sign the document and your `returnUrl` was set to `https://www.docusign.com/developer-center` the callback would look like:

```
https://www.docusign.com/developer-center?event=decline
```

Therefore, when you Embed a recipient and they either do not sign in time (due to the 5 min expiration of the URL) or they try to access it more than once (they are one-time use only) your app will need to parse the `returnUrl` to determine what action they took and simply generate a new signing URL when needed.

Comment: So our app would just call the "Get Embedded Signing View" again using the original envelope id, when our user is ready to sign .